# Instagram, Photobucket и Flickr: получить фотографии на iPad

Tags: ipad, xcode, objective-c

Добрый день. Мне необходимо стянуть из этих сервисов (`Instagram`, `Photobucket` и `Flickr`) фотографии на `iPad`, возможно ли это?

Стянуть фотки человека который залогинился!

P.S. так же буду благодарен ссылкам на гайды (`RUS`, `ENG`)!

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Есть такая штука, называется API. И еще есть google, где можно по запросу найти ответ.

Comment: Если б я нашел ответы, я бы подсказал другим, а не спрашивал бы это у тех кто уже работал с подобными вещами =))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- [Instagram](http://instagram.com/developer/)
- [Photobucket](http://pic.photobucket.com/dev_help/WebHelpPublic/Content/FAQ/FAQOverview.htm)
- [flickr](http://www.flickr.com/services/api/)